# Online Letter of Recommendation from Supervisor

Tags: management, education, recommendation-letter

There is a scholarship program for current employees in our company to go to graduate school.

The Graduate school in question require letter of recommendation from supervisor via online.

It's been more than 10 years I've been in University, and back then when I asked for letter of recommendations, the person would give hardcopy in sealed envelope.

Now, Graduate school website says:

> We ask that you register your recommenders or third-party
>   recommendation service in our online application system.

So far, I have my current supervisor, and past supervisor whom I can ask.

How do I approach? Do I simply say, please register for this online system, or do I create an account and password for them, ask them to log in and change it. Is there anything else I should do

Bottom Line: How to make it easy for supervisors past and present to provide letter of recommendation for this online format?

Answer (score 6):

Ask them to register for the online system and, if you know your supervisors aren't tech savvy, offer to help them if they need it.

Alternatively, you could just ask them what they prefer: "The graduate school requires recommenders to register with their online application system. Can I just send you the link or would you prefer that I create the accounts for you?"

If the graduate school offers any help resources on registering, include those links in your email.

Comment: +1 for asking.  They might back out if they find out their information is going into a database somewhere.  In which case you could ask the school if you could send in an old fashioned letter (albeit maybe by email).  After all, they said "We ask" rather than "We require".